How to create a regex pattern with specific conditions for spaces and underscores?
I need help creating a regex pattern with the following conditions:

It can be the empty string.

It can allow alphanumeric characters.

For special characters, only space or underscore is allowed.

It cannot contain consecutive underscores (_) or spaces ( ).

It cannot contain 3 or more underscores (_) or spaces ( ).

If underscore (_) or space ( ) is present, the first occurrence of _ or space must be after at least 3 characters. (e.g.: 123_)

The second occurrence of _ or space must be before at least 4 alphanumeric characters.


(123_AB_YYYY)--> Valid ---> Since it has 4 alphanumeric after second underscore
(123_AB_YYY)--> InValid Since it has 3 alphanumeric after second underscore
Valid example:

123_ABC_ERRR

Not Valid:

123__
123_VBV_HH_

Can someone help me frame this regex pattern in JavaScript?

Surely rule 5 is implicitly covered by rule 4?

How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

123_GHG_ -- example for 7

it does not satisfy the 5 condition
123_GGG_DDDD_
Invalid

@MageshMaggi Try: ^(?:(?!(?:.*[_][^_]{1,2}[_]|.*[\s][^\s]{1,2}[\s]|.*([\s_])\1))[\w\s])*$? Does it cover all rules?

Sorry again it is failing here 123_rrr_355_ on 5 condition
it should not allow more than 2 underscore or space

What about rule 5, is e.g. Foo_Bar_Baz_123 valid or not? (it contains three underscores). Further is e.g. Foo Bar_Baz_123 valid? (one space, two underscores)

As per rule 5 , entire string should not contain more than two underscore or space
Foo_Bar_Baz_123 - Invalid since it contain more two undescore
Bar_Baz_123 - valid

It can be end with space/underscore but it cannot start with that refer rule 6

Is an underscore next to a space allowed? E.g. 123_ 45

No either _ or space will satisfy all above condition

Here is my try, still being unsure about some rules hope it helps!

@bobblebubble can you comment this as answer i will mark it as answer

Would Foo Bar_Baz_123 Baa be valid? For rule 5, does "cannot contain 3 or more" counts underscore and space separately or together?

@MageshMaggi I vote for HaoWu's very neat pattern! Even without lookaheads. There are minor differences in what it matches, but maybe it still satisifies your need.

Here's a regex that might satisfy your description:
/^(?:[a-z\d]{3,}[_ ]?){0,2}[a-z\d]*$/i

^                    # beginning of the text
  (?:                # non-capturing group 
     [a-z\d]{3,}     # 3 or more alphanumeric (the i flag ensures A-Z can also be matched)
     [_ ]?           # followed by an optional underscore or whitespace
  ){0,2}             # the group can repeat 0 to 2 times, meaning there can only be up to 2 underscore/whitespace exist in your text, and they're separated by at lease 3 alphanumerics
  [a-z\d]*           # any number of alphanumetics after that
$                    # end of the text

See the test cases.

Edit
According to the clarified information, the regex is slightly more complicated:
^(?:[a-z\d]{3,}[_ ](?:[a-z\d]{2,}[_ ][a-z\d]{4,})?)?[a-z\d]*$

^                                  # beginning of the text
  (?:                              # the first optional non-capturing group 
     [a-z\d]{3,}[_ ]               # 3 or more alphanumeric (the i flag ensures A-Z can also be matched), followed by an underscore or whitespace
     (?:                           # the second optional group
       [a-z\d]{2,}[_ ][a-z\d]{4,}  # if the second underscore occurs, it must be preceded by at least 2 alphanumerics, and after it must has at least 4 alphanumerics
     )?                            # the second optional group ends
  )?                               # the first optional group ends
  [a-z\d]*                         # any number of alphanumetics after that
$                                  # end of the text

See the updated use cases

One change in 7 th Conditions

The second occurrence of _ or space must be before at least 4 alphanumeric characters.

(123_AB_YYYY)--> Valid ---> Since it has 4 alphanumeric after second underscore
(123_AB_YYY)--> In Valid Since it has 3 alphanumeric after second underscore

According to the added information, I've updated my answer, see if it helps
